# Read values from local.setting.json while debugging test

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

i don't seem to be able to read anything from this file in an azure functions when running or debugging a test, however it works fine when debugging the whole application locally.. can anyone explain why at all ?

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "xyz": 123
  }
}

var res = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("xyz");
```

ty..

my suspicion is that it is due to the 'debug' being initiated from another project (Test project), and the local.settings.json does not get bundled up with the project being tested ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suspicion is spot on. Only the Azure Functions Runtime Host actually knows to read settings from that file and merge them into the overall AppSettings. When you run in a test project, the Azure Functions Runtime Host is not involved and therefore you don't get access to them.

The *simplest* way to solve this would be to reflect all the same setting keys/values into your test project's `app.config` file under the standard `<appSettings>` section.

Comment: great ty, i added an app.config, and applied transformation from app.debug.config, and it works great - thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I added the settings programatically to minify the chances that sensitive data reach version control.

```
class LocalSettings
{
    public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}

public static void SetupEnvironment()
{
    string basePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\MyAzureFunc");
    var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocalSettings>(
        File.ReadAllText(basePath + "\\local.settings.json"));

    foreach (var setting in settings.Values)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(setting.Key, setting.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great - there's probably a built in GUI way to do this, but this works better at least for me

Comment: That bit of code while being rediculously simple is FRCKEN AWESOME!

Comment: This is indeed great for local machine running of tests - but what's the approach for making this work on the build server part of CI/CD? local.settings.json won't even be checked into source control and may contain secrets. Function app has its settings in App Settings Configuration, including perhaps some secrets pulled from KeyVault). Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkZ. yes that's the elegant part here, once settings are marshalled into Environment variables then all code works as-it-is... so you just need to have an EnvironmentSetup interface that can run when local (this implementation) and a different implementation that reads from the CI/CD pipeline storage... it might yell out to Azure Key Vault, or just a secured file in Blob Storage, etc. vs the local file.

Comment: @CajunCoding ended up setting the env variables from KeyVault but the trouble is the names don't line up 100% so it was more of a manual mapping (from keyvault secret name to env var name) which is unfortunate but unique to our setup