# Azure Functions Testing Functions With Static Properties

Tags: azure-functions

I can test my Azure Function using Xunit like this:

```cs
var req = GenerateReq();
var res = await MyFunc.Run(req, logger);
```

If in my function I generate a CosmosDb DocumentClient like this:

```cs
    static DocumentClient docClient = GetCustomClient();

    private static DocumentClient GetCustomClient()
    {
        string cosmosUrl = string.Empty;
        string cosmosKey = string.Empty;
        cosmosUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmosUrl");
        cosmosKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmosKey");
        DocumentClient customClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosUrl), cosmosKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
                RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
                {
                    MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                    MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30
                }
            });
        return customClient;
    }
```

When I try to access the docClient I am am getting an exception:

```
The type initializer for 'MyFunc.Get' threw an exception.
```

is there a way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by a bad static constructor, or by bad inline initialization of static properties/fields. For instance:

```cs
class MyFunc
{
    static MyFunc()
    {
        //buggy code here
    }
    static DocumentClient docClient = Buggy_GetCustomClient(); // <-- or here
}
```

Above will cause a `TypeInitializationException` prior to the first usage of `MyFunc`.

**Do you have the environment variables `cosmosUrl` and `cosmosKey` defined when that code runs?** If not, that's likely the cause. `GetCustomClient` will end up throwing an exception, and that will get wrapped in `TypeInitializationException`.

As suggested in Napoloeon's answer, I would recommend using dependency injection to get an instance of `IDocumentClient` (assuming you are using function v2). Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299834/1250853) that shows how to inject and use `IDocumentClient` in Azure Functions v2. Official documentation for Azure function's DI support is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

Comment: Should I be able to set a breakpoint on GetCustomClient? When documentClient is called It throws the exception immediately and that code soes not seem to run..

Comment: It's not possible to set a breakpoint in statically initialized fields or static ctors. One way to do this would be not do static initialization. So change to `static DocumentClient docClient;` And then in the MyFunc.Run() method call: `docClient = GetCustomClient();` This should allow the breakpoint to be hit.

Comment: It was the enviroment variables causing the problem initially.I have them in Azure but also in local.settings.json but XUnit is not pickup the local.settings.json file which is really annoying anyway around this?

Comment: This SO Answer gives the answer to keeping the keys OFF  Git Hub and setting the Envirmoment variables. Thanks for your help grrreat answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307861/read-values-from-local-setting-json-while-debugging-test

Comment: i would recommend against doing DI blindly as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by using the startup class and setting up dependency injection.  Then instead of generating the DocumentClient you can inject the IDocumentClient interface its using. From there, you can mock the IDocumentClient during your test.

I wrote about setting the startup class [here](https://ikethe.dev/azure-functions-adds-dependency-injection/)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely be using Dependency Injection to solve this. Currently, you will be using your actual `DocumentClient` in your unit tests which is bad practice - you should be using a **mock** of the `DocumentClient` so you can control it's behaviour.

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), create a Startup.cs file and register your client:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IDocumentClient client = GetCustomClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(client);
        }

        private static DocumentClient GetCustomClient()
        {
            string cosmosUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmosUrl");
            string cosmosKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmosKey");

            DocumentClient customClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosUrl), cosmosKey, new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
                RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
                {
                    MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                    MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30
                }
            });
            return customClient;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can inject an `IDocumentClient` in your function as an input binding:

```cs
[CosmosDB("DatabaseName", "CollectionName")] IDocumentClient documentClient
```

And in your unit test you can mock `IDocumentClient` using a library such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

```cs
private Mock<IDocumentClient> _mockDocumentClient = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();    

var req = GenerateReq();
var res = await MyFunc.Run(req, logger, _mockDocumentClient.Object);
```